# Jmeter throws error on Encryption - using Public Key

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am currently working in a application where RSA Encryption is being used for Encrypting sensitive data. I have tried incorporating the standard encryption method but it is throwing errors. I have selected the language Groovy. Can someone throw light on whether i am doing it right?

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec
def publicKey = '5dy47yt7ty5ad283c0c4955f53csa24wse244wfrfafa34239rsgd89gfsg8342r93r98efae89fdf9983r9gjsdgnsgjkwt23r923r2r0943tf9sdg9d8gfsgf90sgsf89grw098tg09s90ig90g90s903r5244r517823rea8f8werf9842tf24tf42e0132saf9fg6f65afa43f12r103tf4040ryrw0e9rtqtwe0r9t04ty8842t03e9asfads0fgadg675'
def x509PublicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.decodeBase64())
def keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance('RSA')
def key = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509Publickey)
def string2Encrypt = '("testinga@gmail.com|testingb@gmail.com").'
def encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance('RSA')
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key)
def secretMessage = string2Encrypt.getBytes('UTF-8')
def encryptedMessage = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessage) 
def encodedMessage = encryptedMessage.encodedBase64().toString()
vars.put('encodedMessage',encodedMessage)
```

The Output Error i am getting

```
Response Code: 500
Response Message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: x509Publickey for class: Script4

SampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
def x509PublicKey

              ^ mind the capital K
```

and

```
def key = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509Publickey)
                                              ^ mind the lower-case k
```

in Groovy they're absolutely different beasts and case sensitivity matters a lot, choose one option and stick to it and "your" script will start working as expected (or at least this error will go away)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Syntax](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: It did work. However, i am getting a different error this instance. The error is.    javax.script.ScriptException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=39, too big.

Comment: It indicates the problem with the public key contents itself. Also I don't think you should be using RSA to encrypt the data directly